# Intent Service running properly on android 9 when app is in background

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, android-8.0-oreo, android-intentservice

I have an Intent service & a BroadcastReceiver.

As per background limitation on Android Oreo & above, the background applications(when an application is not foreground ) cannot use the started service. When you call **startService**() method from the background applications simply through the IllegalStateException.

But In my case, My intent service is running properly even when the app is in the background.
I am using ADB cmd to trigger broadcast.

Please correct where I am missing.

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.TEST --es maxCountValue 10 -n com.example.servicedemo/.MyReceiver
enter code here
```

BroadcastReceiver class

```
class MyReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "CompleteReceiver", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        if (intent!!.action.equals("android.intent.action.TEST")) {
            val mIntent = Intent(context, MyIntentService::class.java).apply {
                Log.v("MyIntentService", intent.data.toString())
                this.putExtra("maxCountValue", 100)
            }
            context?.startService(mIntent)
        }
    }
}
```

Intent Service

```
private const val SERVICE_NAME = "MyIntentService"

class MyIntentService : IntentService(SERVICE_NAME) {
    private val handler = Handler()

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        showToast("Job Execution Started")
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        showToast("Job Execution onStartCommand")
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        showToast("Job Execution onDestroy")
    }
    override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        val maxCount = intent!!.getIntExtra("maxCountValue", -1)

        for (i in 0 until maxCount) {
            Log.d(SERVICE_NAME, "onHandleWork: The number is: $i")
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100)
            } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                Log.d(SERVICE_NAME, "Exception: ")
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun showToast(msg: String) {
        handler.post {
            Toast.makeText(this@MyIntentService, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest :

```
<service android:name=".MyIntentService"/>

        <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TEST" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

"The definition of background for purposes of service limitations is distinct from the definition used by memory management; an app might be in the background as pertains to memory management, but in the foreground as pertains to its ability to launch services."

-

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

PS that's the whole purpose of services